# Android EditText MultiLine drawable gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am trying to achieve the following (see image) on an EditText using android drawable property.

I have tried using `android:gravity="bottom"` with no success.

And there is no `android:drawableGravity` property as you can see.

[image]

[image]

Current Code:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_full"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_input_circular"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_attach_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="4"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_full"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_half_full"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_full"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_half_full"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
```

Comment: Create a linear layout .. orientation horizontal. add image button or image view and edit text.  Give linear layout a background.,And add gravity to the button

Comment: @Avinashkumawat thanks so much - Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213540/1936925

Comment: your welcome  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Avinashkumawat

```
<LinearLayout
    ....
    android:background="@drawable/bg_input_circular"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    <ImageButton
        ....
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <EditText
     .... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Works Perfectly

[image]

Comment: Well i want to, u know, to help other people who might need it in the future. @Chirag

Comment: Not only you should post the answer, but also you should mark it as "accepted" . I find this question very interesting. @ThunderRoid